# Handling Security in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I've got a challenge to do a bit of row level security in SSRS which involves running some SQL logic to filter the returned result set based on a simple security model.

1. I pick up the current user's username and match it to a list of departments. Each user will only see the departments on their approval path. This bit is easy and works fine.
2. There are a number of users who are in the Finance business area and these people need to bypass the security model and see every department. This query simply selects every department regardless of the current user.

My question is how do optionally include both so that Finance users see everything and everybody else only sees their own departments?

It sounded easy on the face but I'm struggling to think of the best & simplest method and my searches have come to nothing so far as it is difficult to know the right question to ask Google, etc.

The solution can be done in either the data query or in SSRS itself but I can't go back and modify the database - I have to work with what I have.

Brief overview of the data structure...

`USER` table has `user_id` and `department`, `DEPT` table has `department` and `business area`.

Finance is a business area which contains many departments.

Any user that has a department which rolls up to Finance must be able to see ALL departments and business areas.

I hope this is thorough enough for somebody to give me a nudge in the right direction. It's probably staring me right in the face but I have major time pressures so can't spend forever on it. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to explain how you are implementing your row level security. Does every row have a 'department' in it and you're filtering on that? The usual way you do optional filtering is instead of just ..`and row.department = User.Department and..` you'd use `and (row.department = User.Department OR User.department='Finance') and....`. That seems vague but you''ll need to post more info about how the row level security is set up.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct table.col1, table,col2  
  from table 
  join user 
    on ( user.ID = 'userone' and department.area = 'finance' )
    or ( user.ID = 'userone' and department.dept = user.dept' )
```

Comment: Thx. It's slightly different than that. 

All users see 'their' departments (every row has user & dept) except Finance users who see EVERY dept.

I'm simply presenting a list of departments in a drop down for them to select.

The pseudo code for this is something like...

IF localvarUserId IN (SELECT userid where Bus Area = Finance) THEN SELECT all departments
ELSE SELECT departments WHERE userid = localvarUserId

I'm struggling to come up with the SQL for it.

Comment: That is exactly what that SQL does.

Comment: Thx for the input but no it doesn't actually. It's close but not quite right. Due to a couple of reasons- The Bus Area of Finance is on the dept table. not the user table. And there are departments not mapped to users which still need to be shown. These are never returned with this SQL. I've come up with a working solution below that looks a little messy but works and returns the correct results for all users within a second.

Comment: Then just change the table to departmet

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to have a UserDepartment table and simply add all departments when adding a finance user. And set it up so that the department table has a trigger to add any new departments to all finance users.

This makes it simple to query, it gives you the flexibility to add other users who can see more than their department if you need to later. It also avoids all sorts of poorly performing queries with OR conditions complex logic.

Comment: Thx, but I didn't have the luxury of going back to the database design. I had to produce a piece of SQL or some SSRS logic to achieve it using only what is currently available in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple way of handling this in SSRS.

Have two datasets in your report. One without any filters. And one with restrictions, on the lines of

```
username = @CurrentUserName
```

You can use the `SELECT SUSER_NAME()` to get the username of current user. Have this stored in the parameter `@CurrentUserName`.

Have two tables in the same place sourcing from the two datasets you had above.

For the next part, you need to be aware of the "Hidden" property in SSRS.
Do a look up for the current username. If it belongs to 'Finance', display the table without any restrictions and hide the other table. If not, hide the first table and display the second(filtered) one.

Comment: Thx. I thought of something like this but I have many reports and some are far too complex for this to be feasible. It would work though for a simple view.

Comment: Your question doesn't tell that. Anyways, did you try adding filters on the report dataset using expression, which can do custom filtering?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I appear to have cracked it with a piece of SQL that gives me the desired results. There may be other, or better, ways to achieve this but here's my solution...

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user, d.department
FROM department d
JOIN user u ON 
 CASE
  WHEN u.user = @UserId AND u.user NOT IN (SELECT u.user FROM user u JOIN department d ON u.dept = d.dept WHERE d.bus_area = 'Finance') AND u.dept = d.dept THEN 1
  WHEN u.user = @UserId AND u.user IN (SELECT u.user FROM user u JOIN department d ON u.dept = d.dept WHERE d.bus_area = 'Finance') AND d.dept IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
 END = 1;
```

If anybody can improve it please feel free.